# How do I develop code to scrape data, date by date automatically using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic, web-scraping

Situation: I am trying to develop python code with pandas to scrape the currency, date by date (one by one) automatically. And store that data in Mysql DB. I want to make the all process automatically(may be with crontab). Now, I write statistical code in that I need to change link every time by date to scrape every date data.

Question: want to scrape data from webpage using pandas date by date automatically. and store in mysql. I tried the following code which is statistical(need to change link after changing the date):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *
url = 'https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1date=2018-10-24'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
#print(df)


# TO DELETE 2nd COLUMN
#df.drop('inv. 1.00 USD', axis=1, inplace=True)
del df['inv. 1.00 USD']

# TO PRINT ALL DATA IN LIST
df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)
print(df.values.tolist())

# TO TAKE DATE DIFFERENCE IN LIST
diff_date = datetime.today()
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-13', diff_date)
print(dates)
```

In this code, Now I need to change link for every date So want to make it automatic(Automatically code should take date by given range)and scrap data and put that data in list of list format to store in DB.
So please guide me..
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: `url = 'https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1date={}'.format(some_date)` where `some_date` is your variable date string from `dates`

Comment: I've removed the Mysql tag because that portion of your design is not actually related to what you are asking. Your question boils down to how you create a variable string. Once you have that (look into string formatting as suggested in my first comment) then you can concentrate on the pandas and then the SQL

Comment: @roganjosh, "some_date is your variable date string from dates" i couldn't understang. can you explain practically

Comment: hi, do you want data from 2018-10-13 to 2018-10-24? like for 12 days? your question is not clear